# Delooping maps between H-spaces 

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Hi,

this question is related to my question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67551/weak-homotopy-equivalence-of-h-spaces). Suppose, I have a topological group $G$ and an $A_{\infty}$-space $H$, which is a CW-complex. Furthermore, I have a map $\varphi \colon G \to H$, that induces an isomorphism of groups $[X, G] \to [X,H]$ for *finite* CW-complexes $X$.

> Is this enough to deloop $\varphi$,
>   i.e. does there exist a map $B\varphi
> > \colon BG \to BH$. Or can I at least 
>   deduce a weak equivalence between $BG$ 
>   and $BH$ from this?

btw.: What is the "standard" reference for $A_{\infty}$-spaces and $H$-spaces nowadays? Or for Segals $\Gamma$-spaces?

Comment: $H$-spaces may not have classifying spaces.

Comment: I think you should emphasize that the isomorphism $[X, G] \to [X, H]$ is an isomorphism of *groups*, not just sets.  This then yields the condition that $\pi_0(H)$ is a group and that $H$ has a classifying space.

Comment: @Scott: Thank you. I corrected this.
@Torsten: Hmm, in the case I have in mind, H is actually a Gamma-space, so it should have a classifying space. What are the conditions for an H-space to have a classifying space?

Comment: It should have a given $A_\infty$-structure. Note that the actual choice of structure affects what the classifying space would be so you must specify it. A $\Gamma$-structure is stronger but again the choice of $\Gamma$-structure will affect what classifying space you are talking about.

Comment: changed $H$-space to $A_{\infty}$-space according to Torsten's comment

Comment: You still have the same problem though in a slightly different form: A map on classifying spaces induces an $A_\infty$-map on the spaces and vice versa). Your condition even with both $G$ and $H$ being CW-complexes is weaker than that it only says that the map respects the products up to homotopy not up to higher homotopies which is what is required to be an $A_\infty$-map.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not: $S^3$ admits uncountably many loop space structures (c.f. Rector "Loop structures on the homotopy type of $S^3$"), but only $12 (= \vert \pi_6(S^3) \vert)$ H-space structures (c.f. James "Multiplication on spheres (II)").